# Consvertion from int to float and back gives different results C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, undefined-behavior

I'm trying to understand is this undefined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    int integer_number = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    std::cout << integer_number << std::endl;

    float float_number = static_cast<float>(integer_number);
    std::cout << float_number << std::endl;
    
    integer_number = static_cast<int>(float_number);
    std::cout << integer_number << std::endl;

    float_number = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    std::cout << float_number << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

output of a program:

```
2147483647
2.14748e+09
-2147483648
3.40282e+38
```

compiling with flags :  -std=c++20 -Wall -Wpedantic -Werror -Wconversion -O0

[Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xzx19x18b)

Comment: If I recall correctly, it is undefined behavior to assign a float to a int when the float is out of range of the int.  On some platforms, the max int `2147483647` can round up to `2147483648` when stored into a float.  (Because int has 32-bit precision, and float has 24-bit precision.  Commonly; but it is platform dependent.)

Comment: @Eljay when your int is 32 bits but the mantissa of a float is only 24 bits, something's gotta give. And yes that's platform dependent, but I haven't seen a non IEEE compliant float in forever.

Comment: @Eljay that's correct. Both GCC and Clang throws `runtime error: 2.14748e+09 is outside the range of representable values of type 'int'`: https://godbolt.org/z/5WMGfczbb

Comment: @phuclv that surprises me, doing a run time check against limits would add too much overhead. I wonder how they do it?

Comment: @MarkRansom that's the [ASan/UbSan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) in [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html), Clang and MSVC which obviously only work when you enable the feature

Comment: @MarkRansom • I get to work with some oddball platforms, some of which don't have IEEE 754 floats.  :-(  I also got to work on an experimental 128-bit `int` operating system project, but it has since been abandoned (due to moving from Intel x86-64 to ARM).  The sanitizers do add a nominal amount of overhead.